# Plotting incomplete elliptic integral of 1st kind

Tags: r

I wanted to set a small dataframe in order to plot myself some points of the incomplete elliptic integral of 1st kind for different values of amplitude `phi` and modulus `k`. The function to integrate is `1/sqrt(1 - (k*sin(x))^2)` between `0` and `phi`.Here is the code I imagined:

```
v.phi <- seq(0, 2*pi, 1)
n.phi <- length(v.phi)
v.k <- seq(-1, +1, 0.5)
n.k <- length(v.k)
k <- rep(v.k, each = n.phi, times = 1)
phi <- rep(v.phi, each = 1, times = n.k)
df <- data.frame(k, phi)
func <- function(x, k) 1/sqrt(1 - (k*sin(x))^2)
df$area <- integrate(func,lower=0, upper=df$phi, k=df$k)
```

But this generates errors and I am obviously mistaking in constructing the new variable df$area... Could someone put me in the right way?

Comment: There are several issues. First `upper` should be a numeric value, not a vector. See `?integrate` for details. Second (I'm not sure about this one though..), `func` should only take one numerical argument, whereas it takes two in your example. That said you could probably calculate something like `df$area[i] <- integrate(func, lower = 0, upper = df$phi[i], k = df$k[i]` in a for-loop (or apply). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapply`:

```
df$area <- mapply(function(phi,k){
  integrate(func, lower=0, upper=phi, k=k)$value
}, df$phi, df$k)
```

However that generates an error because there are some values of `k` equal to `1` or `-1`, while the allowed values are `-1 < k < 1`. You can't evaluate this integral for `k = +/- 1`.

Note that there's a better way to evaluate this integral: the incomplete elliptic function of the first kind is implemented in the `gsl` package:

```
> integrate(func, lower=0, upper=6, k=0.5)$value
[1] 6.458877
> gsl::ellint_F(6, 0.5)
[1] 6.458877
```

As I said, this function is not defined for `k=-1` or `k=1`:

```
> gsl::ellint_F(6, 1)
[1] NaN
> gsl::ellint_F(6, -1)
[1] NaN
> integrate(func, lower=0, upper=6, k=1)
Error in integrate(func, lower = 0, upper = 6, k = 1) : 
  non-finite function value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stéphane ! `mapply` is perfect for what I wanted; (`gsl` is still unknown to me; maybe useful, but I do prefer the `mapply`version)

Comment: @Andrew Glad to help. Could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ?